# Do you need a visa to transit Abu Dhabi airport?

Tags: layovers, transit-visas, auh

I'm flying Etihad Airways to Melbourne and I've a 14 hours layover at Abu Dhabi.

Some say that as long as you are inside the airport terminal you don't require a transit visa while some say you need a transit visa if your layover is more than 10 hours.

Can I stay inside the airport without a transit visa?

Comment: What is your nationality? That'll likely make a big difference

Comment: i just want to know if one can stay inside the airport without a transit visa if the layover time is 14 hours. i arrive at terminal 3 and depart from terminal 3 and i don't intent on going out of the airport terminal. can i wait at the departure?

Comment: Hi may I know if you ended up getting a visa or having a transit without problems?

Answer (score 3):

You need transit visa only if you want to go out from the airport to the city. If you stay in airport, you will be in a transit zone without passing the boarder. In this case you no need to have transit visa.

However, for 14 hours you may see a lot of interesting things in a city. More information about visas you may find there: http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/check-in-and-passport-control/immigration-and-visas.aspx

> If you are a citizen of one of the following countries, you will be
>   issued with a free-of-charge visit visa upon entry: UK, France, Italy,
>   Germany, the Netherlands, Belgium, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Austria,
>   Sweden, Norway, Denmark, Portugal, Ireland, Greece, Finland, Spain,
>   Monaco, Vatican, Iceland, Andorra, San Marino, Liechtenstein, Poland,
>   Slovenia, Slovakia, Czech Republic, Lithuania, Hungary, Latvia,
>   Estonia, Malta, Cyprus, Croatia, Romania, Bulgaria, United States,
>   Australia, New Zealand, Japan, Brunei, Singapore, Malaysia and Hong
>   Kong.

Comment: Thank you for the information.. i'm not from the countries listed above so i'm not eligible for visa on arrival. The only thing i can do is wait for 14 hours at terminal 3 for my connecting flight. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I travelled in July-2017 and my transit time was 8 hrs 5 min.
There was No Visa needed. I stayed inside the terminal for the entire time.

DO NOT rely on Etihad agents as some of the agents told me that I needed a Visa if my stay is more than 8 hrs.