# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit-visas, uae, etihad

I am travelling from Moscow to Trivandrum via Abu Dhabi. I arrive in Abu Dhabi Terminal 3 at 19:00 and my next Etihad flight is at 2:40 out of Terminal 1, a layover of 7 hours 40 minutes.

Do I need a transit visa? Can I remain airside between Terminal 3 and Terminal 1? I am an Indian passport holder.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Whether or not you ever need a visa is highly dependent on your nationality; please [edit] your post to indicate which country's passport you are traveling on.  It seems likely, however, that you will find the answer in *[Do you need a visa to transit Abu Dhabi airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/do-you-need-a-visa-to-transit-abu-dhabi-airport)*

Answer (score 2):

Without your nationality, it's difficult to offer to a specific response.

However, your carrier, [Etihad Airlines](http://www.etihad.com/en-us/before-you-fly/visas/), provides the link needed to determine whether you need a visa and, if so, to obtain it.

> Take advantage of our visa services to make that memorable trip to the UAE.
>
> We have partnered with [TT services](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/) to provide you with convenient visa services.
>
> **Visa on Arrival**
>   Citizens of eligible countries/regions are allowed to enter the UAE without a visa prior to arrival as long as they are carrying a valid passport that will not expire within six months of their arrival date. Immigration officials may grant a visit visa, which is valid for 30 days, on arrival at the port of entry.
>
> **Other destinations**
>   We encourage all guests to be familiar with the visa requirements of the countries/regions you are travelling to. Please check with your travel agent or visit the respective embassy's website for more information.
>
> [**TT Services**](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/)
>
> - [Countries/regions eligible for visa on arrival](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/do-i-need-a-visa/)
> - [Visa types and fees](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/visa-fees/)
> - [Documents required](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/document-required-for-uae-visas/)